# How to stop showing selected value in <Select> options

Tags: html, jsp

I have a 5 drop-downs in my JSP page

```
<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select> 


<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select> 


<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select> 


<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select> 


<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
```

Initially all select list have a default option selected that is "Choose one"

now i want that if i select one item from list 1, now this item is not showing in all other

if select from list 2 then it should not available for all other lists.

I am done code in JSP pages.

thanks for any help, i really need to do it

Comment: You'll want to use javascript for this. Moreso, a javascript framework like jquery can make it even easier to make.

Comment: yes you right, have you give me any help on this actually how should i implement this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery you can simply do this:

```
$('select').change( function() {
    var selected_value = $('option:selected', this).val();
    $('select').not( $(this) ).each( function(i,v) {                            
        $('option', v).each( function(j, x) {
            if( x.value == selected_value ) {
                 $(x).remove();
            }                
        });            
    });
});​
```

Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3AZ/1/

Note that this is by no means the best implementation, but it does, basically, do what you want it to do.

EDIT:
Buggy as noted by @RoXon below. Here's an updated version, still buggy, but it should give you an idea on how to solve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3AZ/6/

Comment: Have you played with your demo? Is totally buggy.

Comment: Not a bit. How is it buggy? .. edit: Nevermind, I see it now. I did say it wasn't the best implementation, though. =P